# Symfony : How to fetch data in a table which is not an entity

Tags: ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to know if it's possible to use Doctrine to fetch some data in a table which is not an entity.

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection;

$connection->fetchAll("SELECT ...");
```

I tried to use the Connection namespace. this one is working with my entities, but not with the table i want.

This code is actually working, but i'm using PDO to connect the database to execute the query. So the Ajax request is not fast enough. And my SQL query must be prepared to avoid security breaches.

Thanks for your help

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/search", name="map_api_search")
 */
public function search(Connection $connection, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager): Response
{
    if ($ajaxRequest = $request->getContent()) {
        $requestContent = json_decode($ajaxRequest, true);

        $content = $requestContent["content"];

        $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();

        $connectionParams = array(
            'dbname' => 'smartport',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1:3306',
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        );

        $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);

        // Prepare the query
        $sql = "SELECT nom, lon, lat, id FROM `chimie_stations2` WHERE nom LIKE '%$content%' AND aasqa = 'PACA'";
        // Execute SQL query
        $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
        //Prepare an array to push all the results from the query
        $results = array();
        // Processing...
        while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $results[] = $data;
        }

        if (($results)) {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'result' => true,
                'results' => json_encode($results),
            ]);
        } else {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'result' => false,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `$entityManager->getConnection()` to retrieve the connection object?

Comment: PDO is faster than Doctrine. Look for how to do prepared statements with PDO. That would make SQL query secure enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prepare your SQL query :

```
public function myFunction(EntityManager $entityManager) 
{
    $connection = $entityManager->getConnection();

    $sql = 'SOME SQL HERE';
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```